# iPhone Jailbreak development profiles

Tags: iphone, xcode, jailbreak

Im developing apps with a iPhone4 and my old 3G is my 2nd device for testing. 
So, is it possible to jailbreak the Phone and run apps with xcode?

Does anyone have expirience with that, a jay or a ney ?

cheers endo.

**Edit:** According to the answers it is possible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can jailbrake an 3G and use it to test.

But if you already have a developer certificate you simply add the 3G to the list of development devices. For that no Jailbreak is needed.

Only benefit I see is to run code on the device without having Xcode attached and read in /var/syslog the output of NSLog statements.

But then MobileTerminal (from Cydia) is broken in iOS 4 and I haven't bothered with installing the latest Beta. I find in more comfortable to ssh across from a full sized computer and read /var/syslog or other files in that way. So again, I am not using much the features offered by jailbreaking.

Main benefit for using a 3G is to have a device on 3.1.3 and to test if the App performs well in terms of speed and backward compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use it for development as Olaf said. I have been doing the same, no issues what so ever. Except that beware, you might have issues with Push Notifications. 
Push notifications, especially productions certs, wont work with jail broken phones. I learnt that the hardway.

other than that, i did'nt find any issues.